# Cast of 'long' to 'id' is disallowed with ARC - iOS Dev

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

Converting my project to ARC but need help with these two bits of code to do with uploading and downloading files:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite{
[delegate performSelector:progressSelector withObject:(id)(100*totalBytesWritten /totalBytesExpectedToWrite)];
```

and then the following code, specifically the last line:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)con // IN
didReceiveData:(NSData *)data                // IN
{
NSLog(@"%s: self:0x%p\n", __func__, self);
NSInteger       dataLength;
const uint8_t * dataBytes;
NSInteger       bytesWritten;
NSInteger       bytesWrittenSoFar;

dataLength = data.length;
dataBytes  = (const uint8_t * )data.bytes;

bytesWrittenSoFar = 0;
if(fileStream!=NULL)
{
do {
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)bytesWrittenSoFar);
    bytesWritten = [fileStream write:&dataBytes[bytesWrittenSoFar] maxLength:dataLength - bytesWrittenSoFar];
    assert(bytesWritten != 0);
    if (bytesWritten == -1)
    {
         [self downloadSucceeded:NO];
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        bytesWrittenSoFar += bytesWritten;
    }
}
    while (bytesWrittenSoFar != dataLength);
}
dataSize+=data.length;
if(dataSize==downloadSize)
{
    downloadDidSucceed=TRUE;
}
[delegate performSelector:progressSelector withObject:(id)(long)(100*dataSize/downloadSize)];
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
 [delegate performSelector:progressSelector withObject:(id)(long)(100*dataSize/downloadSize)];
```

try this

```
[delegate performSelector:progressSelector withObject:[NSnumber numberWithLong:(100*dataSize/downloadSize)]];
```

Comment: Better solution - don't use `performSelector:withObject:`. There's no reason to be using that here.

Comment: What would I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C there is distinction between scalar values like int/long/float/double and object types.

the id type is an anonymous object type. You don't know what it is, but you know that it is an object.

A `long` is not, and cannot be, an object. It is a simple scalar value. that's why the compiler isn't letting you cast your long to an ID type.

Sh_Khan's answer of wrapping your long value in an `NSNumber` solves the problem by creating an object that **contains** your value. You could also use an `NSValue` to get the same effect, but `NSValue` can represent things like structs that you can't represent with `NSNumbers`.